# How to move WPF Chart LineSeries continuously from Left To Right when data comes from server?

Tags: wpf, charts

I've a line series wpf chart and i need to bind this chart continuously from server and it can move left to right when data comes from server. But I've no idea how to do this by using wpf chart line series so any one help me how can i do this?

Thanks,
@nagaraju

Comment: Move your x-axis min and max to move the chart.

Comment: user can't do anything itselft automatically moves left to right when data comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var xAxis = yourChartObject
            .ActualAxes
            .OfType<LinearAxis>()
            .FirstOrDefault(ax =>   ax.Orientation == AxisOrientation.X);
if (xAxis != null)
{
    xAxis.Maximum -= (points you want to move);
    xAxis.Minimum -= (points you want to move);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I haven't used it anytime but here is some thing. If you have datetime on X-axis most of the charts convert datetime into double value using ToOADate method. If that is the case with your chart as well first convert the value back to datetime then AddMinutes

This is how you do that

```
xAxis.Maximum = DateTime.FromOADate(xAxis.Maximum).AddMinutes(mintuestoadd);
```

Comment: my x-axis having time blocks so how can i max n min time?

Comment: in XAxis.Maximum i'm getting null but in xAxis.ActualMaximum i'm getting the correct value same as ActualMinimum but i can't change these actualmax n min becoz they're read only.

Comment: xAxis.Maximum += TimeSpan.Parse(xAxis.ActualMaximum.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                xAxis.Minimum += TimeSpan.Parse(xAxis.ActualMinimum.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));

Comment: so i tried as above bt not working, in my graph it refreshes every five seconds and from there i need to move previous 5 seconds to left and fresh 5 seconds to present display.

Comment: Why are you assigning TimeSpan? Use DateTime.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5525/discussion-between-maheep-and-nag)